# C++ metaprogramming - compile time search tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, template-meta-programming

*UPDATE: sorry for confusing terms - I do not need a binary-tree, but segment-tree or interval-tree.*

Imagine I have to statically initialize a search tree each time mine program is executed.

```
Tree t;
t.add(10, 'Apple');
t.add(20, 'Pear');
t.add(50, 'Orange');
...
t.add(300, 'Cucumber');

..
// then I use it.
int key = 15;
String s = t.lookup(key) // Returns 'Apple' ( as the key is between 10 and 20)
```

The keys and values in a tree are "static", hard-coded, but have to be maintained from time to time. Is there are metaprogramming trick how to organise key values into binary-search tree (or a skip list) during compile time?

For example the whole search tree is implemented directly in code `.text` and nothing is held in `.data`? I can also "predict" number of keys and provide order them.

Comment: What is your motivation for doing this?

Comment: You could write a template, I suppose.

Comment: @Brian Let's say that the "section" with all `t.add()` is machine generated from parser generator. So when I have 127 keys it will generate a code which will perform up to 7 conditional jumps till the input is clasified.

Comment: Why does that need to happen at compile time?  Anyway, templates are Turing complete, so.

Comment: The application does not run as a deamon, so the search tree must be initialised on each execution and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: What prevents you from writing a template?  If you've come here expecting a code sample, you may be barking up the wrong tree.  This site doesn't specialize in code implementations, and Stack Overflow frowns on "write my code for me" questions, so...?

Comment: All of the entries in the example are integers (even if represented by `double` values), is that the case?

Comment: yes, the keys are integers. I just wanted to illustrate that searched value can be something in between them. I can not put the keys into a hash map.

Comment: From your exposition, it sounds like you really shouldn't be doing what you're trying to do: it sounds like you have a goal of ease of maintainability, and have absolutely no evidence that doing this initialization has any meaningful performance impact at all. Thus, your efforts look like you're trying to optimize something that doesn't matter, which will probably come at the cost of making the thing that *does* matter worse. In fact, I would advise the opposite of what you're trying to do: find a way to make this list easier to maintain, even if it's at the expense of extra initialization.

Comment: [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) might be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you are making a mountain out of a molehill here,
and that it's because:-

- You believe that to *statically initialize* something in C++ you
  have to do it *at compiletime*.
- Either you are not acquainted with the
  concepts of *upper* and *lower bounds* or else you don't know that the 
  {upper|lower} bound of `v` in a [partially] ordered sequence `S` can be 
  determined by binary search of `S`, and that you can count on the Standard Library
  to do it at least that efficiently.

I think you want to have a statically initialized data structure mapping
integer keys to string literals such that, at runtime, you
can query it with an integer `n` and very efficiently
retrieve the string literal `s` (if any), whose key is the largest
that is not larger than `n` - with the additional proviso, presumably,
that `n` is not larger than all keys.

If that is right, then the statically initialized data structure you need 
is simply  a *statically initialized map* `M` *of integers to string literals*.
Template meta-programming is not in the frame.

Because of the (presumed) proviso that that a query shall fail for `n` larger 
than all keys, you will need to include a sentinel value in `M` with a key 1 
larger than the largest you want to find.

Then, for runtime integer `n`, you query `M` for the upper bound of `n`. 
The upper bound of `n` in `M` is the smallest key larger than `n`, if any. 
If the returned iterator `it` is `M.end()` then you have no string for `n`. 
Otherwise, if `it == M.begin()`, then *every* key is greater than `n`, 
so again you have no string for `n`. Otherwise, there must exist a `<key,value>`
located by `--it`, and that `key`must be the largest key that is *not*
larger than `n`. So your string for `n` is that `value`.

```
#include <map>

static const std::map<int,char const *> tab = 
{
    { 2,"apple" },
    { 5,"pear" },
    { 9,"orange" },
    { 14,"banana" },
    { 20,"plum" },
    { 20 + 1,nullptr }
};

const char * lookup(int n)
{
    auto it = tab.upper_bound(n);
    return it == tab.begin() || it == tab.end() ? nullptr : (--it)->second;
}
```

Prepend that to this example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 21; ++i) {
        cout << i;
        char const *out = lookup(i);
        cout << " -> " << (!out ? "Not found" : out) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the output will be:

```
0 -> Not found
1 -> Not found
2 -> apple
3 -> apple
4 -> apple
5 -> pear
6 -> pear
7 -> pear
8 -> pear
9 -> orange
10 -> orange
11 -> orange
12 -> orange
13 -> orange
14 -> banana
15 -> banana
16 -> banana
17 -> banana
18 -> banana
19 -> banana
20 -> plum
21 -> Not found
```

Now `tab` in this program is a *static* data structure, but it is not
initialized at *compiletime*. It is initialized in the *global static
initialization* of your program, before `main` is called. Unless you
have a requirement to shave nanoseconds off your program startup, I
can't think why you would need the map to be initialized at compiletime.

If nevertheless you *do* require it to be initialized at compiletime,
it is just a little fiddlier than this. You will need the map to be
a [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) 
object, meaning the compiler can construct it at compiletime; and for
that it must be of a [*literal type*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_literal_type);
and that means you cannot use `std::map`, because it is not a literal type.

Therefore you will have to use instead:

```
constexpr std::pair<int,char const *> tab[] 
{
    { 2,"apple" },
    { 5,"pear" },
    { 9,"orange" },
    { 14,"banana" },
    { 20,"plum" },
    { 20 + 1,nullptr }
};
```

or similar, and implement `lookup(n)` in essentially the manner shown,
but invoking `std::upper_bound` upon `tab`. There you'll find the
slightly fiddlier bits, which I'll leave you for the exercise, if you
want it.

Comment: You're right mine request was kind of premature optimization. The contract for mine application is clear: one execution, one initialization, one lookup. I can not do anything about that. So I tried to create a code where there will be no initialization at all - and all the constants will be compiled-in in the code. See mine "answer" for the result. But then I found that  reasonable compiler will generate similar code for much readable input source code.

Answer (score 2):

I finally created what I wanted to achieve. It's overcomplicated and it looks like compiler optimizers are much smarter then I thought.

```
// Log "function"
template <int N>
struct LOG
{
    static const int value = LOG<N/2>::value + 1;
};
template<>
struct LOG<0>
{
    static const int value = 0;
};

// pow "function"
template <int N>
struct POW
{
    static const int value = POW<N-1>::value * 2;
};
template<>
struct POW<1>
{
    static const int value = 2;
};

template<>
struct POW<0>
{
    static const int value = 1;
};

// Pair <key, value> to be a payload in a type list
template<int k, char v>
struct Pair
{
    static const int key = k;
    static const int value = v;
};

// type list manipulator - access n-th element
template <size_t, class...> struct element;
template <class TT, class...TTs>
struct element<0, TT, TTs...>
{
    typedef TT type;
};
template <size_t K, class TT, class...TTs>
struct element<K, TT, TTs...>
{
    typedef typename element<K-1, TTs...>::type type;
};

template<class... Ts>
struct V;

// Binary split search algorithm (pure templatized)
template<class T, class... Ts>
struct V<T, Ts...> : private V<Ts...>
{
    template<size_t N = sizeof...(Ts), size_t level = LOG<sizeof...(Ts)+1>::value>
    struct impl
    {
        template<size_t IDX>
        inline static char search_impl(size_t n)
        {
            using namespace std;
            static const int depth = LOG<N>::value;
            static const int layer = depth - level;
            static const int key   = element<IDX, T, Ts...>::type::key;
            static const size_t left_idx  = IDX - ( N / POW<layer + 2>::value + 1);
            static const size_t right_idx =
                IDX + ( N / POW<layer + 2>::value + 1) > sizeof...(Ts) ?
                sizeof...(Ts) :
                IDX + ( N / POW<layer + 2>::value + 1);             

            //std::cout << setfill('*') << setw(layer) << ' '
            //    << "Level:" << level << " of:" << depth << std::endl
            //    << std::setw(layer) << ' ' 
            //    << "IDX/val/layer/POW/level: "
            //    << " " << IDX
            //    << "/" << key
            //    << "/" << layer
            //    << "/" << POW<layer>::value
            //    << "/" << level
            //    << "/" << left_idx
            //    << "/" << right_idx
            //    << std::endl;
            if ( n < key )
                return V<T, Ts...>::impl<N, level-1>::template search_impl<left_idx>(n);
            else
                return V<T, Ts...>::impl<N, level-1>::template search_impl<right_idx>(n);       
        }

    };

    template<size_t N>
    struct impl<N,1>
    {
        template<size_t IDX>
        inline static char search_impl(size_t n)
        {
            static const int key   = element<IDX, T, Ts...>::type::key;
            static const char value1 = element<IDX-1, T, Ts...>::type::value;
            static const char value2 = element<IDX, T, Ts...>::type::value;
            if ( n < key )
            {
                //std::cout << " *" << value1 << ' '  << IDX << std::endl;
                return value1;
            } else {
                //std::cout << " *" << value2 << ' '  << IDX << std::endl;
                return value2;
            }
        }
    };

    static void print()
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << ' ' << T::key << ' ' << (char)T::value << std::endl;
        V<Ts...>::print();
    }
    static char search(size_t n)
    {
        static const size_t level = LOG<sizeof...(Ts)+1>::value;
        static const size_t N = sizeof...(Ts);
        static const int height = LOG<N>::value;
        static const size_t root_idx = N / 2 + 1;
        static const int key = element<root_idx, T, Ts...>::type::key;
        //std::cout << "Level:" << level << " of:" << height << std::endl
        //    << "IDX/val: "
        //    << " " << root_idx
        //    << "/" << input[root_idx]
        //    << std::endl;

        static const size_t left_idx  = root_idx - ( N / POW<2>::value + 1);
        static const size_t right_idx = root_idx + ( N / POW<2>::value + 1);

        if( n < key)
            return V<T, Ts...>::impl<N, level-1>::template search_impl<left_idx>(n);
        else
            return V<T, Ts...>::impl<N, level-1>::template search_impl<right_idx>(n);
    }
};

template<>
struct V<>
{
    static void print()
    {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = std::stoi(argv[1]);

    typedef V<
    Pair<  0x1,'a'>,
    Pair< 0x11,'b'>,
    Pair< 0x21,'c'>,
    Pair< 0x31,'d'>,
    Pair< 0x41,'e'>,
    Pair< 0x51,'f'>,
    Pair< 0x61,'g'>,
    Pair< 0x71,'h'>,
    Pair< 0x81,'i'>,
    Pair< 0x91,'j'>,
    Pair<0x101,'k'>,
    Pair<0x111,'l'>,
    Pair<0x121,'m'>,
    Pair<0x131,'n'>,
    Pair<0x141,'o'>
    > TV;

    std::cout << (char)TV::search(i) << std::endl;

    return 0;
};
```

So this is it. Mine goal was to "force" the compiler to put all the constants into the code. As nothing is kept in the data segment. The resulting code inlines all the search_impl<*> methods together and the result contains only "cmp" and "jae" instructions. But it looks like a reasonable compiler will do this anyway, if the array to be searched is defined as const static.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `switch` to do the lookup.

The compiler is free to use a jump table, binary search, or any other technique to optimize the lookup. For most switch tables, the compiler will generally emit the fastest possible thing.

```
switch (key)
{
    case 10: return "Apple";
    case 20: return "Pear";
    ...
}
```

Comment: this would be a hash map. I also have to search for values between keys.

Comment: If you use GCC, you can still make that work.  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html

Comment: Case ranges look good!! - they would be sufficient a comfortable solution if I could use gcc.  I just need to "inject" at compile time some kind of decision making tree into mine application. After a hour of google-ing I found this, but it looks quite frightening: http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1616

Comment: Yeah, that's an amazing technique but I'd also be a little frightened of it... :)